# Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Exp - Compile is ok but its not running

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, runtime-error

I write some programmes. But they arent working.. Now, i have a basic programme. Compile is ok.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: tracker6, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  trancker6.cpp
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

But I click run button then:

```
This program is out of date:
  tracker6 - Debug Win32
Would you like to build it?
```

And I say yes. After that:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0321ef3d in tracker6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
reading location 0x00000000.

Break     Continue    Ignore
```

And I say Continue but its not working. This error comes again.

Please help me for running this codes:

```
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
    IplImage* frame;
    while(1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
}
```

Comment: please, don't use the outdated c-api, use the c++ api instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem would seem to be that your program is expecting a command line argument (that's what `argv[1]` means) but you haven't supplied one. So your program crashes.

I guess that the command line argument is meant to be a file name.

You presumably know what this program is meant to do so why did you think you could run it without supplying a file name?

If you want to make it run the first thing I would try is to replace the reference to a command line argument with a hard coded file name. I.e. replace

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
```

with

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "somefile" );
```

EDIT:

Apparently this is a video streaming program, so replace "somefile" with the name of the file containing the video you are trying to stream.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your right. But i try lots of thing after your comment. İts not working again...

i have lots of errors.. like these;

`'tracker6.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\AA1\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\tracker6\Debug\tracker6.exe', Symbols loaded.
'tracker6.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'tracker6.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
...
The program '[7772] tracker6.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: @AydınAyaydın The most likely thing wrong is that your program cannot find the video file that you are trying to play. Probably because you haven't told it where the file is properly.

Answer (score 0):

just try after checking the 'Mycrosoft Symbols Server' 
debug->options and settings->symbols

Comment: First of all im sorry. because im new that OpenCV and İmg proccessing. But i try to learn it. Because of this thank you for yours help. I did your advice but some symbols load, some symbols not.. this is;

`C:\OpenCV2.2\bin\opencv_highgui220d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
C:\OpenCV2.2\bin\opencv_core220d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
C:\OpenCV2.2\bin\opencv_ffmpeg220d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file`